# could not find driver (SQL: select * from `homes`) on Laravel shared hosting

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I uploaded my laravel project to a shared host. But I keep getting the error

```
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `homes`)
```

But it runs well on my localhost.
What could I possibly do to resolve this?

You can check it for yourself on  https://www.simdansendit.com

Comment: You will need `PDO_mysql` for this to work

Comment: The error clearly says that the driver is not installed on the server. So install the driver.

Comment: What is you PHP version on server? This error is because on server  `php-mysql` extension is missing, please install it and enable it.